# Python: A very simple star patterned box

Tags: python, box

I have to make a box that is empty from inside.
I want to make a box that looks somthing like this:

```
+++
+ +
+++
```

The width can vary. This is my code so far.

```
width = int(input("Enter box size(3-30) >>>"))
top = "+" * width
middle = 
bottom = "+" * width
```

Not sure what to put in the middle.

Comment: middle = "+" + " "*(width-2) + "+"

Answer (score 2):

Since the middle is `"+"` followed by `width - 2` empty spaces and then another `"+"`, you can set middle to `"+" + " " * (width - 2) + "+"`.